# Bash Script - Store PHP INI location in a variable

Tags: php, linux, bash

I am trying to create a bash script to install various things on my server as I develop.  The idea being that it runs on deploy and if I change server, I can just run the script and everything will work.

So far I have this:

```
#!/bin/sh
apt-get update  # To get the latest package lists
apt-get install imagemagick ghostscript

INI_LOC=echo php -i | grep 'php.ini' | grep 'Loaded Configuration File'
```

Which is halfway there. $INI_LOC now has the value "Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini"

My question is, how do I change this variable to only show "/etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini"?

The next step is to then use this variable to add "extension=imagick.so" to the php.ini file, if it hasn't already been added.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the output of `php -i`? As such your syntax for running the command is running the pipe commands and storing the output in a variable is wrong. You need to use command substitution?

Comment: It will always be empty if you dont install php first.

Answer (score 1):

> $INI_LOC now has the value "Loaded Configuration File =>
>   /etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini"
>
> My question is, how do I change this variable to only show
>   "/etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini"?

Seems like you just need to remove the "Loaded Configuration File => " string from `INI_LOC`:

```
INI_LOC=`echo $INI_LOC | sed 's/Loaded Configuration File => //'`
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the filename of currently `php.ini` in use:

```
INI_LOC=$(php -i|sed -n '/^Loaded Configuration File => /{s:^.*> ::;p;q}')
```

Then, to check if it has `extention=imagick.so`:

```
sed -n 's:^[\t ]*::;/^;/d;/^$/d;s: *= *:=:;/extension="*imagick.so"*/{p;q}' <"$INI_LOC"
```

If `extension=imagick.so` not found, then insert it in the `[PHP]` block while making the backup file with `sed -i~`

```
sed -i~ '/^[\t ]*\[PHP\][\t ]*$/{s:$:\nextension=imagick.so:}' "$INI_LOC"
```

Now, combine all those above:

```
INI_LOC=$(php -i|sed -n '/^Loaded Configuration File => /{s:^.*> ::;p;q}')
if [ -f "$INI_LOC" ]; then
  FOUND=$(sed -n 's:^[\t ]*::;/^;/d;/^$/d;s:[\t ]*=[\t ]*:=:;/extension="*imagick.so"*/{p;q}' <"$INI_LOC")
  if [ -z "$FOUND" ]; then
    sed -i~ '/^[\t ]*\[PHP\][\t ]*$/{s:$:\nextension=imagick.so:}' "$INI_LOC"
  fi
fi
```

---

1. `sed -n '/^Loaded Configuration File => /{s:^.*> ::;p;q}')`: find the line containing `Loaded Configuration File =>` at the beginning of that line; print (p) then quit (q)
2. `s:^[\t ]*::;`: remove all spaces in the beggining of all lines
3. `/^;/d;/^$/d;`: delete (skip) blank lines and commented lines
4. `s:[\t ]*=[\t ]*:=:;`: remove all blanks around equal sign
5. `/extension="*imagick.so"*/{p;q}`: if `extensions=imagick.so` or `extensions="imagick.so"` is found, then print (p) that line and quit (q)
6. `sed -i~ '/^[\t ]*\[PHP\][\t ]*$/{s:$:\nextension=imagick.so:}' "$INI_LOC"`: insert `extension=imagick.so` in the `[PHP]` block

Sorry for my bad English, because I am not an English spoken person.